# Match and change tag value after xsl copy-of select node()

Tags: xml, xslt

I am receiving different xmls. One of them has tag with value true/false which I have to replace with 1/0. 
My xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tag1>
        <tag2>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(ERRORMSG) > 0">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ERRORMSG" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
</xsl:template>
```

My xml:

```
<tag2>
    <tag3>
        <tag4>
            <tag5>abc</tag5>
            <tag6>
                <tag7>
                    <tag8>false</tag8>
                    <tag9>true</tag9>
                </tag7>
            </tag6>
        </tag4>
    </tag3>
</tag2>
```

How I can do that? I can't delete `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>` because I am receiving different templates and in one of them I have to replace the specific tag value (tag8, tag9) to 1/0 if true/false.

Comment: Use two templates: an *identity transform* template to copy all nodes as a rule, and a template matching the true/false elements as an exception to the rule. -- Note that templates cannot be nested.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by modifying the XSLT to first copy all the nodes using *identity transform* and then using templates to modify the values in `<tag8>` and `<tag9>` nodes.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="true" select="'1'" />
    <xsl:variable name="false" select="'0'" />

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag8">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$false" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag9">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$true" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<tag2>
    <tag3>
        <tag4>
            <tag5>abc</tag5>
            <tag6>
                <tag7>
                    <tag8>0</tag8>
                    <tag9>1</tag9>
                </tag7>
            </tag6>
        </tag4>
    </tag3>
</tag2>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this :

**XSLT 1.0**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(.) = 'true' or normalize-space(.) = 'false']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="normalize-space(.) = 'true'">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(.) = 'true' or normalize-space(.) = 'false']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="if(normalize-space(.) = 'true') then '1' else '0'"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
 <tag2>
    <tag3>
        <tag4>
            <tag5>abc</tag5>
            <tag6>
                <tag7>
                    <tag8>0</tag8>
                    <tag9>1</tag9>
                </tag7>
            </tag6>
        </tag4>
    </tag3>
</tag2>
```